# Match string until specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have the string:

"hello world; some random text; foo;"

How could I select everything until ';'

in other words I want the first match to be: `"hello world"`

the second match to be `" some random text"`

etc.

things that I have tried:

```
string s = "hello world; some random text; foo;";
Regex r = new Regex(".+?;");
var match = r.Match(s);

while(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
    // first match is "hello world"!! but this turns out to be an infinite loop
    match.NextMatch();
}
```

I know I can use the Regex.Split() method but I want to use this technique intead... what am I doing wrong? why does the `match.NextMatch();` method does not returns the next match?

Comment: *"I know I can use the `Regex.Split()` method but I want to use this technique intead"* - so...why, if it does what you need it to and probably more efficiently than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: `what am I doing wrong?` You are using the wrong technique. Use `Regex.Split`. Or better yet, in this simple example, just use `string.Split`.

Comment: because I am building a longer regular expression where I want to find multiple matches. I am stuck at the middle of my regex expression because of this problem...

Comment: Try breaking it into smaller pieces then. You don't need to - and may be unable to - solve your problem in one go.

Comment: Yeah I know I can break it into smaller peaces. I am learning regex and I am tired of breaking everything down and replacing a lot of text. For example I know I will be able to use the Regex.Split method in here but I will have to keep track of every chunck and replace it with the main string being parsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would *strongly* recommend that you use `Regex.Split` as you indicated, or even `string.Split` for this simple example.

But, if you still want to use a loop whatever reason, you could do something like this:

```
string s = "hello world; some random text; foo;";
Regex r = new Regex(".+?;");
for (Match m = r.Match(s); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

The problem with your specific example is that `NextMatch` returns a *new* match. It doesn't mutate the current Match. Changing `match.NextMatch();` to `match = match.NextMatch();` in your while loop should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to fix the problem:

```
string s = "hello world; some random text; foo;";
Regex r = new Regex(".*?;{1}");
var match = r.Match(s);

while(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
    // move match index to avoid getting the same match
    match = r.Match(s, match.Index + match.Length);
}
```